# Add barButtonItems in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

Hi in my iPhone application i need to set barButtonItems in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. In ios 6 it works fine:

```
-(void) manageContacts
{
    peopleNavigationController = [[PeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    peopleNavigationController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [peopleNavigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    peopleNavigationController.delegate = self;
    peopleNavigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"back",nil)
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(pressBack)];
    peopleNavigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPerson)];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:peopleNavigationController animated:YES];


}
```

But in ios 7 there is default buttons. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `topViewController` of the `navigationController` is **nil**, you might need to set an initialized VC as a rootViewController to your `peopleNavigationController`.